# C++: sudoku (copy board)

Tags: c++, sudoku

I'm new to c++ and got a problem when doing homework (sudoku).

Instruction said: "you have to create a new board being a copy of the current board (use
the copy constructor and allocate the board from the heap with new)."

I've tried (it's wriiten in board.cc):

```
#include "board.h"

// Search for a solution, returns NULL if no solution found
Board* Board::search(void) {
  Board b = new Board(&this);
  ...
  return b;
}
```

Got error msg:

```
lvalue required as unary '&' operand.
```

I've also tried:

```
Board* Board::search(void) {
   Board b;
   Board *b3;
   b3 = &b;
...
   return b3;
}
```

This got no prob when comp. but it doesn't work either when running.

How to do it? Really need help here, thx!

Here is some code for board.h:

```
class Board {
private:
  Field fs[9][9]; // All fields on board

public:
  // Initialize board
  Board(void) {
    // Uses the default constructor of Field!
  }
  // Copy board
  Board(const Board& b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
          fs[i][j] = b.fs[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  // Assignment operator for board
  Board& operator=(const Board& b) {
    if(this != &b){
       for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
             fs[i][j] = b.fs[i][j];
          }
        }
     }
     return *this;
   }
   ....
```

Complete instruction can been found here: 
http://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.136980!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/2-2.pdf

Code: http://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.136981!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/2-2.zip

Comment: Board b = new Board(&this); That's not right. If you want to use "new", you need to define it as Board *b.

Comment: Sudoku solver, yeah! Explicit memory handling, yikes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
Board b = new Board(&this);
```

to:

```
Board *b = new Board(*this);
```

Comment: Also, if you are using a C++11 compatible compiler, I suggest you return a std::unique_ptr<Board> or a std::shared_ptr<Board> in order to manage your new Board instance. They are found at #include <memory>

Comment: This tackles only part of the problem. My guess is that `Board` does not have a constructor that takes a `Board**` as argument...

Comment: thx, but I still got the error msg: lvalue required as unary '&' operand :(

Comment: Sorry - missed the second problem as pointed out by @David R - now updated.

Answer (score 5):

```
Board b = new Board(&this);
```

That line has two errors, the first one is that if you allocate with `new`, the type will be `Board *`, and not just `Board`. The second error is that if you want to use the copy constructor you should pass the element pointed by `this`, not the address of `this`:

```
Board * b = new Board( *this );
```